# Move NAs to the end of each column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, na

I have such a data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), b = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

> df
    a  b  d
1  NA NA NA
2  NA NA NA
3   1 NA NA
4   2  1 NA
5   3  2  1
6   4  3  2
7   5  4  3
8   6  5  4
9   7  6  5
10  8  7  6
```

In each column, I'd like to move the non-`NA` values up to the start, and move the `NA`s to the end:

```
> df.out
    a  b  d
1   1  1  1
2   2  2  2
3   3  3  3
4   4  4  4
5   5  5  5
6   6  6  6
7   7  7 NA
8   8 NA NA
9  NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA
```

**Update to make my questions clearer..**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(NA, NA, 1, 5, 34, 7, 3, 5, 8, 4), b = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 57, 2, 7, 9, 5, 12, 100), d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 7, 
2, 8, 2, 5)), .Names = c("a", "b", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")

> df
    a   b  d
1  NA  NA NA
2  NA  NA NA
3   1  NA NA
4   5  57 NA
5  34   2  5
6   7   7  7
7   3   9  2
8   5   5  8
9   8  12  2
10  4 100  5
```

should result in:

```
    a   b  d
1   1  57  5
2   5   2  7
3  34   7  2
4   7   9  8
5   3   5  2
6   5  12  5
7   8 100 NA
8   4  NA NA
9  NA  NA NA
10 NA  NA NA
```

Seems like an easy task but I am stuck on where to start.. Can you help?

Comment: Note that the data actually changed here (looking from a row perspective): is that deliberate, or do you simply mean to sort the NA's to the bottom?

Comment: That's on purpose, I basically want all the numbers to be aligned row-wise, thus each column should be shifted up individually.

Comment: Cannot imagine what you need it for, but I posted an answer. You'll probably want to look out for a data.table solution, they are generally the fastest.

Comment: Wait a minute... are you saying that if you would have a simple vector like `c(NA, 2, 3, 1)`, that the result would have to be `c(2,3,1,NA)`? That would really change this question!

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yes, exactly, sorry if it was unclear, I'll update the question!

Comment: It took some time, but here you go! Your question update does indeed make it very clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After completely misunderstanding the question, here is my final answer:

```
# named after beetroot for being the first to ever need this functionality
beetroot <- function(x) {
    # count NA
    num.na <- sum(is.na(x))
    # remove NA
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    # glue the number of NAs at the end
    x <- c(x, rep(NA, num.na))
    return(x)
}

# apply beetroot over each column in the dataframe
as.data.frame(lapply(df, beetroot))
```

It will count the NAs, remove the NAs, and glue NAs at the bottom for each column in the data frame.

Comment: You don't need to do `as.matrix` in your last example. `apply` coerces to matrix automatically. But you should wrap it in `as.data.frame` to get it back to a data.frame.

Comment: Thanks, but as in Thomas' answer this sorts the values in each columns but I need the order of the rows in each column to stay the same (the position of the NAs should be the only thing that changes )

Comment: Awesome, that's it! I feel honoured :D If commercial software companies were able to produce decent csv output files I wouldn't need this either ;)

Answer (score 14):

Another solution using `lapply` (without sorting/reordering the data- per your comments)

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
df
#     a   b  d
# 1   1  57  5
# 2   5   2  7
# 3  34   7  2
# 4   7   9  8
# 5   3   5  2
# 6   5  12  5
# 7   8 100 NA
# 8   4  NA NA
# 9  NA  NA NA
# 10 NA  NA NA
```

Or using `data.table` in order to update `df` by reference, rather than creating a copy of it (that solution won't sort your data neither)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, names(df) := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))]
df
#      a   b  d
#  1:  1  57  5
#  2:  5   2  7
#  3: 34   7  2
#  4:  7   9  8
#  5:  3   5  2
#  6:  5  12  5
#  7:  8 100 NA
#  8:  4  NA NA
#  9: NA  NA NA
# 10: NA  NA NA
```

Some benchmarks reveal the base solution is the fastest by far:

```
library("microbenchmark")
david <- function() lapply(df, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
dt <- setDT(df)
david.dt <- function() dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))]

microbenchmark(as.data.frame(lapply(df, beetroot)), david(), david.dt())
# Unit: microseconds
#                                 expr      min       lq   median        uq      max neval
#  as.data.frame(lapply(df, beetroot)) 1145.224 1215.253 1274.417 1334.7870 4028.507   100
#                              david()  116.515  127.382  140.965  149.7185  308.493   100
#                           david.dt() 3087.335 3247.920 3330.627 3415.1460 6464.447   100
```

Comment: Congratulations on figuring out what the OP wanted from the get-go.

Comment: I like it. My only other thought on a similar process would be: `lapply(df, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))] )` which is probably less efficient in timings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - sorry, there were so many answers/comments at the same time, so I completely missed yours and only saw it just now!

Comment: I've Updated results per your new data set. The solution remained unchanged

Comment: @DavidArenburg I hope you don't mind, but I added some benchmarks to your answer.

Comment: @Thomas, you are most welcome to do so. Maybe add Thelas solution too. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas - those benchmarks will unfairly disadvantage data.table with such a small dataset.

Comment: @thelatemail my guess I'm doing something wrong here by using `names(df)`, maybe that created these columns again? Not sure...

Comment: @DavidArenburg - i think it's just the tiny overhead of initialising data.table functions. Try it on 100K or 1M rows and i'm sure it's a tonne faster.

Comment: @thelatemail Probably true. This is an odd case of a data structure, though, so I don't want to think about how to generate a huge dataset of this form.

Answer (score 4):

For fun, you can also make use of `length<-` and `na.omit`.

Here's what that combination would do:

```
x <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3)
x
# [1] NA  1  2  3
`length<-`(na.omit(x), length(x))
# [1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Applied to your problem, the solution would be:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) `length<-`(na.omit(x), nrow(df)))
df
#     a   b  d
# 1   1  57  5
# 2   5   2  7
# 3  34   7  2
# 4   7   9  8
# 5   3   5  2
# 6   5  12  5
# 7   8 100 NA
# 8   4  NA NA
# 9  NA  NA NA
# 10 NA  NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got small number of columns, I suggest:

```
data.frame( a=sort(example$a, na.last=T), b=sort(example$b, na.last=T), d=sort(example$d, na.last=T))
```

Best,
Adii_

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na_move` function from package `dedupewider`.

```
library(dedupewider)

na_move(df, direction = "bottom")
#>     a   b  d
#> 1   1  57  5
#> 2   5   2  7
#> 3  34   7  2
#> 4   7   9  8
#> 5   3   5  2
#> 6   5  12  5
#> 7   8 100 NA
#> 8   4  NA NA
#> 9  NA  NA NA
#> 10 NA  NA NA
```