# Left shift columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data set like this

```
temp <- structure(list(col_1 = c("", "P9603", "", "", "11040", 
"80053"), col_2 = c("84484", "80061", "", "80061", "A0428", "85025"
), col_3 = c("V2632", "82310", "", "", "", "86357"), col_4 = c("J1170", 
"84305", "62311", "80061", "", ""), col_5 = c("", "86708", "J0690", 
"", "", "")), .Names = c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", 
"col_5"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

   col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
1:       84484 V2632 J1170      
2: P9603 80061 82310 84305 86708
3:                   62311 J0690
4:       80061       80061                        
5: 11040 A0428                  
6: 80053 85025 86357
```

Is there a possibility to shift the columns like this

```
   col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
1: 84484 V2632 J1170              #LEFT SHIFT 1
2: P9603 80061 82310 84305 86708  #NO CHANGE
3: 62311 J0690                    #LEFT SHIFT 3
4: 80061 80061                    #LEFT SHIFT 1 FOR FIRST ITEM, 
                                  #LEFT SHIFT 2 FOR 2ND ITEM 
5: 11040 A0428                    #NO CHANGE
6: 80053 85025 86357              #NO CHANGE
```

I am shifting columns left, if the value on left is empty

Comment: Related: [How to move cells with a value row-wise to the left in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651606/how-to-move-cells-with-a-value-row-wise-to-the-left-in-a-dataframe). Just replace `""` with `NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Grouped by the sequence of rows, `unlist` the Subset of data.table (`.SD`), `order` by the logical vector (`un==''`), convert to `list` and then set the names with the original column names after removing the 'grp' column

```
setnames(temp[, {un <- unlist(.SD); as.list(un[order(un=='')])},
    .(grp = 1:nrow(temp))][, grp := NULL], names(temp))[]
#  col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
#1: 84484 V2632 J1170            
#2: P9603 80061 82310 84305 86708
#3: 62311 J0690                  
#4: 80061 80061                  
#5: 11040 A0428                  
#6: 80053 85025 86357
```

---

Or another option is to `melt` into long format after creating a sequence column, then `dcast` it to wide format

```
dcast(melt(temp[, n := seq_len(.N)], id.var = 'n')[order(n, value == ''),
     .(value, variable = names(temp)[1:5]), n], n ~ variable)[, n := NULL][]
```

Comment: the solution with dcast is really elegant, works well on large dataset as well. The first one also works but is slower. I cannot thank you enough akrun sir!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way, but this works:

```
library(plyr)

x = apply(temp,1,function(x) {t(as.matrix(unname(x[nchar(x)>0])))})
x = do.call(rbind.fill.matrix, x)
x[is.na(x)]=''
colnames(x) = colnames(temp)[1:ncol(x)]
x = as.data.frame(x)
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
1 84484 V2632 J1170            
2 P9603 80061 82310 84305 86708
3 62311 J0690                  
4 80061 80061                  
5 11040 A0428                  
6 80053 85025 86357
```

Basically, find all entries per row with `nchar(x)>0` and row bind them using rbind.fill.matrix, so they are left-aligned. Then replace the `NA`'s with `''`, replace the column names with the original ones (take into account that there may be less columns left), and convert to dataframe.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one left shift, a simple data.table version

```r
temp

# col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
# 1:       84484 V2632 J1170      
# 2: P9603 80061 82310 84305 86708
# 3:                   62311 J0690
# 4:       80061       80061      
# 5: 11040 A0428                  
# 6: 80053 85025 86357          

temp[col_1 == "", 1:(ncol(temp)-1)  := temp[col_1 == "", 2:ncol(temp)]]
temp

# col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
# 1: 84484 V2632 J1170            
# 2: P9603 80061 82310 84305 86708
# 3:             62311 J0690 J0690
# 4: 80061       80061            
# 5: 11040 A0428                  
# 6: 80053 85025 86357
```