# how to transform marginal data (reporting line data) using R

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph, network-analysis

I have the following data:

| Name | Line Manager |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B1 |
| A3 | B2 |
| B1 | C1 |
| B2 | C1 |
| A4 | C1 |

I want to transform the data to the following 2 ways. After the transformation, I could find all the members within one line manager including the members not directly reporting to him/her. Note that there may be more than 3 hierarchies in the actual case.

I guess it may related to the network analysis but not quite sure. Using the data manipulation of package dplyr is one way. However, I just wonder is there an easy way to do that by a build-in function in some R package?

(1)

| Name | Line Manager |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B1 |
| A3 | B2 |
| A1 | C1 |
| A2 | C1 |
| A3 | C1 |
| A4 | C1 |
| B1 | C1 |
| B2 | C1 |

(2)

| Name | LM_Level1 | LM_Level2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A2 | B1 | C1 |
| A3 | B2 | C1 |
| A4 | C1 |  |
| B1 | C1 |  |
| B2 | C1 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the data:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(~Name ,   ~Line.Manager,
"A1" , "B1",
"A2" , "B1",
"A3" , "B2",
"A1" , "C1",
"A2" , "C1",
"A3" , "C1",
"A4" , "C1",
"B1" , "C1",
"B2" , "C1")

# Reshaping to wide
dat <- tidyr::pivot_wider(dat, names_from = Line.Manager, values_from = Line.Manager)
# Moving values to the left - stolen from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26651706/5221626
dat[] <- t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
# Removing empty columns
dat <- janitor::remove_empty(dat, "cols")
# Renaming column names.
names(dat)[2:ncol(dat)] <- paste0("LM_Level", seq_len(ncol(dat) - 1))
dat

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Name  LM_Level1 LM_Level2
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
1 A1    B1        C1       
2 A2    B1        C1       
3 A3    B2        C1       
4 A4    C1        NA       
5 B1    C1        NA       
6 B2    C1        NA
```

I'm finding the 2nd step a little bit awkward, but I can't think of a better way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a try later. I am thinking of using some recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

For (2) (labeled `step_1` here), you can join `df` with itself; connect the join with `line_manager` and `name`.

For (1) (labeled `step_2`), just group by `name` and pivot longer.

Output (2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

step_1 <- 
  df %>%
    left_join(df, by = c("line_manager" = "name"), suffix = c("", "_lvl2")) %>%
    replace_na(list(line_manager_lvl2 = ""))

  name line_manager line_manager_lvl2
1   A1           B1                C1
2   A2           B1                C1
3   A3           B2                C1
4   B1           C1                  
5   B2           C1                  
6   A4           C1
```

Output (1):

```
step_2 <- 
  step_1 %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    pivot_longer(-name, names_to = 'tmp', values_to = 'line_manager') %>%
    select(-tmp) %>%
    filter(line_manager != "")

  name  line_manager
  <chr> <chr>       
1 A1    B1          
2 A1    C1          
3 A2    B1          
4 A2    C1          
5 A3    B2          
6 A3    C1          
7 B1    C1          
8 B2    C1          
9 A4    C1
```

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Name   Line Manager
A1  B1
A2  B1
A3  B2
B1  C1
B2  C1
A4  C1", 
                 sep = "\t", 
                 header = TRUE, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), str_replace, " ", "")) %>%
  janitor::clean_names()
```

Note: I know it's a little odd calling OP's (2), `step_1`, and (1) as `step_2`, but the `step_` indexes are more like the logical order of operations in this transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will take a try later. I am thinking of using some recursive method.