# How would I remove all NA from a table and create a smaller condensed table?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this table

```
NA  JAKUB.VRANA NA  NICKLAS.BACKSTROM   TOM.WILSON  NA  NA
NA  NA  LARS.ELLER  RICHARD.PANIK   T.J..OSHIE  NA  NA
NA  BRIAN.PINHO CONOR.SHEARY    DANIEL.SPRONG   NA  NA  NA
```

And I am looking to remove all NAs and create a table with just three columns with the names

Comment: Based on your input, how _exactly_ should your output look like?

Comment: it should just remove the NAs and condense each row to three columns

Comment: Should the first row look like "JAKUB.VRANA", "NICKLAS.BACKSTROM", "TOM.WILSON"?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Something like this: If your data.frame is named `df`, does `as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])))` return your expected output? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651606/how-to-move-cells-with-a-value-row-wise-to-the-left-in-a-dataframe

Comment: yes, that worked for me. Thank you!