# Placing row values into columns based on corresponding row label

Tags: r

I have two columns in a data frame, one is "Diameter" the other is "Ash". I am trying to transpose the two columns into several columns based on the label in the ash column. This should be simple but it has been a long time since I have used R.

```
X Diameter Ash  
1 0.566176 Apache
2 0.588312 Apache
3 0.590499 Tolk
4 0.607365 Belle Isle
5 0.631185 Tolk
```

I would like it to look like:

```
X Apache Belle Isle Tolk
1 0.566  0.607      0.590
2 0.588  N/A        0.631
```

Comment: Also the actual data columns are 50000 rows long, which is why I didn't manually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plyr` `ldply` with `split`

```
df=plyr::ldply(split(x$Diameter,x$Ash), rbind)
row.names(df)=df$.id
df$.id=NULL
df=data.frame(t(df))
df
  Apache Belle.Isle Tolk
1   0.56        0.6 0.59
2   0.58         NA 0.63
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution groups the data by Ash, creates a new variable using row_number() and then spread the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- tibble(X= c(1:5),
            Diameter = c(0.56,0.58,0.59,0.60,0.63),
            Ash = c("Apache", "Apache", "Tolk", "Belle Isle","Tolk"))

df_2 <- x %>%select(-X) %>%
    arrange(Ash) %>%
    group_by(Ash) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(Ash, Diameter)

df_2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spread` function.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  spread(key=Ash, value=Diameter)
```

This, however, generates 5 rows of data; so we move all values up and push `NA`s down using below function ([from this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869011/move-nas-within-dataframe-in-r)) and filtering out all rows with all `NA`s so you end up with just two rows in this case.

```
move_vals_up <- function(x) {
  num.na <- sum(is.na(x))
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  x <- c(x, rep(NA, num.na))
  return(x)
}
as.data.frame(lapply(data2, move_vals_up)) %>% 
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) > 1)
```

Output:

```
  X   Apache Belle.Isle     Tolk
1 1 0.566176   0.607365 0.590499
2 2 0.588312         NA 0.631185
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could first change your dataframe to a matrix and then use the transpose functions, but this probably isn't what you want because then each entry would be coerced to string values. Because your dataframe is so small, I would recommend the most straightforward way to be:

```
rbind(df$Ash, df$Diameter)
```

Where df is the name of your dataframe